# what you mean by Unable to resolve resource bundle "datamanagement" error occured in flex?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash, actionscript

when will i add Advanced data grid in my project then it shows eror like

```
everity and Description Path    Resource    Location    Creation Time   Id
Unable to resolve resource bundle "datamanagement".
```

but separte mxml file then add it not show any errors .my project i used locale binding for multi language so i add in complier `-locale=English,Japan,Arabic,Dutch,India -source-path=locale/{locale}` so if i add like may be error occured i dont know What's reason  error occurred ? i am seeking soluation  lot of time , unable to find it . if you know kindly explain me

Comment: I had the same error, and adding compilation argument `-source-path=locale/{locale}` made it disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the datavisualization.swc and datavisualization_rb.swc files to your project.

1. right click on Flex sample project, choose properties;

   - go to "Flex Build path", "Library Path" tab;
   - click the "Add SWC" button and add the files

The files should be located in your Flex SDK directory under

/frameworks/libs/

Comment: doing following steps . After that AD add to state and run shows same error resolve resource bundle "datamanagement".